# Scratch Off Label Printing

Tags: print-design, print-production

I am looking to purchase a printer that can print scratch off material, but am having trouble finding any companies that manufacture this type of printer.  Are there any consumer printers available that can print scratch off material onto a standard gloss or matte substrate?